# SetFrame works on iPhone, but not on iPad. Auto resize mask to blame?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, frame, cgrectmake

I'm trying to resize a UITextView when the keyboard shows. On iPhone it works beautifully. When the the system dispatches a keyboard notification, the text view resizes. When it's done editing, I resize it to fill in the initial space. (Yes, I'm assuming the keyboard is gone when the editing stops. I should change that. However, I don't think that's my issue.)

When I resize the textview on the iPad, the frame resizes correctly, but the app seems to reset the Y value of the frame to zero. Here's my code:

```
- (void) keyboardDidShowWithNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

//
//  If the content view being edited
//  then show shrink it to fit above the keyboard.
//

if ([self.contentTextView isFirstResponder]) {

    //
    //  Grab the keyboard size "meta data"
    //

    NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    //
    //  Calculate the amount of the view that the keyboard hides.
    //
    //  Here we do some confusing math voodoo.
    //
    //  Get the bottom of the screen, subtract that 
    //  from the keyboard height, then take the 
    //  difference and set that as the bottom inset 
    //  of the content text view.
    //

    float screenHeightMinusBottom = self.contentTextView.frame.size.height + self.contentTextView.frame.origin.y;

    float heightOfBottom = self.view.frame.size.height - screenHeightMinusBottom;


    float insetAmount = kbSize.height - heightOfBottom;

    //
    //  Don't stretch the text to reach the keyboard if it's shorter.
    //

    if (insetAmount < 0) {
        return;
    }

    self.keyboardOverlapPortrait = insetAmount;

    float initialOriginX = self.contentTextView.frame.origin.x;
    float initialOriginY = self.contentTextView.frame.origin.y;

    [self.contentTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(initialOriginX, initialOriginY, self.contentTextView.frame.size.width, self.contentTextView.frame.size.height-insetAmount)];


}
```

Why would this work on iPhone, and not work on iPad? Also, can my autoresize masks be making an unexpected change?

Comment: is the view a modalView?

Comment: No, it is a UITextView, presented in a UINavigationController.

Comment: but is the `UINavigationController` presented modally?

Comment: @WrightCS No, it's part of a `UITabBarController`, which is loaded from a NIB.

Comment: Yes, there can be problem in property `autoresizeMask`. What value do you set to your text view?

Comment: @Nekto - I use interface builder to set it. Should I manually clear it in code? How?

Comment: No, you can do it via IB. What value did you set?

Comment: You realise that UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey doesn't account for the orientation of your iPad. Could that be something to do with it?

Comment: @bandejapaisa - What are my alternatives?

Comment: Well I'm not guaranteeing this is your problem. You can still use it, but you have to take into account the orientation of the device. The UIWindow API docs give a little guidance on it's usage: "These coordinates do not take into account any rotation factors applied to the window’s contents as a result of interface orientation changes. Thus, you may need to convert the rectangle to window coordinates (using the convertRect:fromWindow: method) or to view coordinates (using the convertRect:fromView: method) before using it.".

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]; and then switch the height and width, but this can be cumbersome - and watch out of FaceUpOrientation's which are waiting to catch you out....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like said @bandejapaisa, I found that the orientation was a problem, at least during my tests.

The first thing, is about the use of `kbSize.height` being misleading, because in Landscape orientation it represents the width of the keyboard. So, as your code is in a `UIViewController` you can use it this way:

```
float insetAmount = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)?kbSize.height:kbSize.width) - heightOfBottom;
```

The `self.interfaceOrientation` gives the orientation of the Interface (can be different from the Device orientation) and the macro `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait` returns `YES` if the given orientation is Portrait (top or bottom). So as the keyboard height is in the `kbSize.height` when the interface is Portrait, and in the `kbSize.width` when the interface is Landscape, we simply need to test the orientation to get the good value.

But that's not enough, cause I've discovered the same problem with the `self.view.frame.size.height` value. So I used the same workaround:

```
float heightOfBottom = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)?self.view.frame.size.height:self.view.frame.size.width) - screenHeightMinusBottom;
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This seems to have solved it on the simulator. I'm going to test it and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Works on the device too! I am sending this out to test soon and I'll award the bounty shortly thereafter. If you don't mind, please explain the first line of code though, I'm a little unsure how it helps.

Comment: I think that checking `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait ` is not correct. I'd rather advice to check using macros `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape`. This is because first return `true` only for one orientation (button is at the bottom - portrait mode too) while second returns yes to both landscape orientations.

Comment: Sorry @Nekto, but what you've said seems wrong. In fact `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait` checks both portrait orientations. _cf._ `UIApplication.h` `#define UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)  ((orientation) == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || (orientation) == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)` see http://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Oh, i was mistaken. Sorry. Thanx +1 =)